# How to manipulate DOM in ubuntu command line without actually rendering the page on the GUI?

Tags: command-line, firefox, cron, browser, websites

I've written a small JS snippet which clicks some buttons in the DOM of a certain target website in a loop.
To run this snippet, I open the target website in firefox. Then I paste this JS snippet in the console and let it do its job. PFA a sample snippet below.

Now the problem is that I want to automate this whole process to avoid actually opening firefox everyday. I would just like to write a cron to do this daily and everything should happen in background. I need to deploy this on a cloud ubuntu VM without a GUI.

Any ideas about how I should proceed?
(I already know that I can use the website's backend API, thereby bypassing the entire DOM manipulation. But I would like to explore other options.)

P.S.: Sample of a code that I enter into the firefox's developer tools console:

```
func = setInterval(function () {
    // Some button that I want to click.
    document.evaluate("/html/body/div[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click();

    // TODO: A break condition (or not)
}, 6000);
```

Comment: You should have a look at slimerjs.